# Cannot get external odbc connection to work in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, odbc

I created a 32 bit DSN and tested it with winsql and can browse the catalog and do queries.  Using excel 2013 32-bit if I do get external data from other data sources > from data connection wizard > ODBC DSN > (MY DSN) > Next >  it give me The Data Connection Wizard cannot obtain a list of databases from the specified data source.  and I can go no further.

What would be causing this and/or how would I debug this?

The connection is obviously working because I can browse it with winsql.

Comment: why a -1?  I can find no other similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have this resolved (kind of).  I believe the issue is that the driver for the dsn does not serve 3.0 sql code which is what excel uses when using the connection wizard.  Using the other micriosoft query option, it connected fine.  Something to try fro anyone stuck on this.